# Bootstrap navbar not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Flask through a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRwy8gtgJ1A), and I can't get the bootstrap navbar to work properly. I picked up the code from the bootstrap examples section. I've tried what other answers suggested around here on similar questions but nothing seems to solve the problem. Code snippets and screenshot posted below. The CSS link I'm using works fine too. I'm a beginner so any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyFlaskApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

  {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

_navbar.html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyFlaskApp</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/articles">Articles</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing **[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/)**, but attempting to use the **[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/)** syntax.

The easiest way to resolve this is to simply import Boostrap 3 instead, which can be done via the URL `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Note that while not necessary for the styling, you'll probably also want to switch the JavaScript to the same version via `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js`.

This simple change corrects your navbar, as can be seen in the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MyFlaskApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- _navbar.html -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyFlaskApp</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/articles">Articles</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)